# What is the "conformance viewer" tool on Compiler Explorer? https://godbolt.org/

Tags: compiler-explorer

I see it as a tool I can add, yet I do not know what it does. I have tried googling, but could not see an answer. Surely this is documented somewhere. Or someone knows and has published it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Conformance View` lets you compile without viewing assembly. This is useful to ensure that your code passes all these compilers, but without the need to have 10 windows open.

---

---

Source:

Couldn't find this on Google but I COULD find it by following the Discuss C++ on the [Cpplang Slack](https://cppalliance.org/slack/) link at the top of [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org).

I searched for the `conformance viewer` tool and saw the messages:

---

##### June 21st 2017

Rubén

> Woop! So with this update there's now a conformance view which you can use to quickly see whether or not the code compilers/generates warnings on different compilers. Like in this dumb example https://godbolt.org/g/16CqgT

Matt Godbolt

> And thanks to Rubén for implementing it!

---

##### September 10th 2018

Rubén

> @steveire conformance view lets you compile a source with up to 10 compilers at the same time, so you dont have to open 10 compiler views

> It lets you see if they compiled/produced warnings/did not compile

> No asm though